# Combinations and Permutations:Making a garland with at least one type of flower

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The following is a question:

How many different choices can be made from 5 roses, 4 marigold and 8 sunflowers if at least one flower is to be chosen for making of garland?

a) 269
b) 270
c) 281
d) 320

This is the explanation provided:

Answer: a
Explanation: Number of ways of selecting roses = (5+1) = 6 ways, number of ways of selecting marigold = (4+1) = 5 ways, and the number of ways of selecting sunflowers = (8+1) = 9 ways. Total number of ways of selecting flowers= 6 * 5 * 9 = 270. But this includes when no flowers or zero flowers is selected (There is no flowers of a different type, hence n=0 => 2n = 20 = 1). Hence, the number of ways of selecting at least one fruit = 270 – 1 = 269.

So, my question is why are we adding the number of each type of flower by one, shouldn't it be 5 times 4 times8? Also what do they mean selecting at least one type of flower? Do we have to perform combinations for only the type of flower or all flowers? Does it mean a garland can be made from one flower only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently, we only care about which flowers are included in the garland, not how they are arranged.  We can select up to $5$ roses, giving six choices: $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$.  Similarly, we can select up to $4$ marigolds, giving five choices, and up to $8$ sunflowers, giving $9$ choices.  Hence, if there were no restrictions, we could form $6 \cdot 5 \cdot 9 = 270$ garlands.  However, one of these garlands would contain no flowers.  Thus, there are $270 - 1 = 269$ ways to select the flowers in the garland if the garland is to be composed of at least one flower.  Notice that a garland need not include a flower of each type.